# Can someone help me understand how this "for" loop works?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
int main(void) {
    long fall, n, k, p, i, j, r;
    long long x, y, a[110][110];
    for(a[0][0]=scanf("%ld",&fall);fall--;printf("%lld\n",y)) {
        for(i=!!scanf("%ld%ld%ld",&n,&k,&p);i<=k+1;i++)
            for(j=0;++j<=i;a[i][j]=(a[i-1][j-1]+j*a[i-1][j])%p)
                ;
        for(y=!(j=1);j<=k+1;y=(y+a[k+1][j++]*x)%p)
            for(x=!((r=n%j)*!(i=-1));++i<j;x=x*(n-i)/((i==r)?j:1)%p)
                ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How does for loop work here? It doesn't follow the syntax as I see.

Comment: Why do you care about obfuscated code?

Comment: I am a beginner. I never met this situation before. I wonder if it is an another way to write for loop.

Comment: It is an unusual way to write a loop. It's code that is not meant to be easily understood, so why try?

Comment: @QuanChen: For a beginner, I would *strongly* advise you to stay away from code like this. You won't learn anything worthwhile from it, and may learn bad coding style.

Comment: @EOF I'm just curious about it. Since you say so I give up.

Comment: It's rubbish code.  Utter trash.  I doubt that anyone will want to do anything with it for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for explanation of garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops have the following pattern:

`for(initial expression; conditional expr; afterthought)`

I'll break down the first loop for you, you should be able to do the rest on your own.

```
for(a[0][0]=scanf("%ld",&fall);fall--;printf("%lld\n",y))
```

The initialization part of this loop is `a[0][0]=scanf("%ld",&fall)`.
`scanf` is used for reading input and returns the number of input values. In this case, it will be `1` and it gets assigned to `a[0][0]`.

`fall--` is the conditional expression. In C, positive numbers are evaluated as true. So this loop will run until `fall == 0`.

`printf("%lld\n",y)` is the afterthought. It gets run after each loop iteration. In this case, it will simply print the value.

Unraveling obfuscated code can be a good learning exercise though you must obviously never use it in practice.

This code abuses the fact that the first and third conditions of the `for` loop does not necessarily need to have anything to do with the loop itself. At its core, the `for` loop simply executes an initial expression, performs the conditional check and executes the afterthought after every iteration.

Comment: Thank you. Very easy to understand now.